# How to have foreign key referencing a set of records, or avoid such case

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

Let's have assemblies composed of some simple parts. We can create a tables for parts:

```
CREATE TABLE part(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                  title text);

INSERT INTO part(title)
          VALUES('part_0'),
                ('part_1'),
                ('part_2'),
                ('part_3'),
                ('part_4'),
                ('part_5');
```

and another table for assemblies:

```
CREATE TABLE assembly(id integer,
                      part_id integer,
                      part_quantity smallint,
                      FOREIGN KEY(part_id) REFERENCES part(id),
                      UNIQUE(id, part_id));

INSERT INTO assembly(id, part_id, part_quantity)
              VALUES( 1,       1,             1),
                    ( 1,       5,             5),
                    ( 2,       3,            10),
                    ( 2,       2,             4),
                    ( 2,       4,             3),
                    ( 3,       1,             5),
                    ( 3,       3,             2);
```

Now suppose, in different contexts the same assembly can have different denominations.
That induces to creation of a new table linking denominations with corresponding **assembly.id** and
allowing to understand the underlying assembly is the same or not:

```
CREATE TABLE denomination(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                          title text,
                          assembly_id integer,
                          FOREIGN KEY(assembly_id) REFERENCES assembly(id));
```

I do not want to use arrays in **assembly** table for **part_id** because it seems that foreign references from array elements, is not allowed. I would like to understand what would be an elegant solution in this case. And why is not allowed to have foreign key referencing a set of records. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> And why is not allowed to have foreign key referencing a set of records instead of single record. Thanks in advance.

I think the problem here is that by definition, a foreign key needs to be a direct correlation with the referenced table.  It cannot be a reference to a set of candidate rows in the referenced table.  [As per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key):

> a constraint that the tuples consisting of the foreign key attributes in one relation, R, must also exist in some other (not necessarily distinct) relation, S, and **furthermore that those attributes must also be a candidate key in S** (emphasis mine)

Therefore, each row in assembly with a non-null `part_id` should reference a single row in the `parts` table.  As such, parts cannot be strictly keyed to denominations, as you basically created an abstraction layer between assemblies and denominations.

However, you `denominations`->`assemblies`->`parts` topology doesn't seem to have any problems (if there are, please state them more clearly--what is it that you need to enforce--and I'll update my answer)

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of more experience, I decided to answer my question. The relational structure of the tables reported in the question is not correct. Here is why: In each assembly can participate many parts, and each parts can be included in many assembly. For example, the assembly with id 1 contains parts with id 1 and 5. On the other hand the part with id 1 participates in the assembly with id 5 as well. So it is clear that we have many to many relationship. To realize this relation correctly we will need three table: the first for assemblies, the second for parts and the third linking table, that will realize the many to many relationship between the first and the second tables:
Tables for parts:

```
CREATE TABLE part(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                  title text);

INSERT INTO part(title)
          VALUES('part_1'),
                ('part_2'),
                ('part_3'),
                ('part_4'),
                ('part_5');
```

table for assemblies:

```
CREATE TABLE assembly(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO assembly(id)
              VALUES(default),  -- value 1
                    (default),  -- value 2
                    (default);  -- value 3
```

linking table:

```
CREATE TABLE assembly__part(assembly_id integer,
                            part_id integer,
                            quantity integer,
                            FOREIGN KEY(assembly_id) REFERENCES assembly(id),
                            FOREIGN KEY(part_id) REFERENCES part(id));

INSERT INTO assembly__part(assembly_id, part_id, quantity)
                    VALUES(          1,       1,        1),
                          (          1,       5,        5),
                          (          2,       3,       10),
                          (          2,       2,        4),
                          (          2,       4,        3),
                          (          3,       1,        5),
                          (          3,       3,        2);
```

Even if records of assembly consists of only one field, a table for assembly must be done. Then from the link table (assembly__part) we can have foreign keys to parts and to assemblies because they are unique in their tables.
If for some other reason we need to have "foreign key referencing a set of records" we can easily achieve this goal writing an appropriate trigger.